# Полная предварительная загрузка страници

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vue.js

Нужна для ускорения загрузки предварительно загрузить всю страницу.
Пробовал загрузить через ajax, но тогда я просто беру разметку и ее воспроизвожу где начинается подгрузка файлов для сайта.

Как можно реализовать полную загрузку сайта, что бы при переходе все уже было загруженно, к примеру на поддомене у меня другой сайт, который перенаправит от другого поддомена.
Он видит страницу навигации, при переходе у него уже готовая станица?
Пробовал на jquery, не плохо было бы и на vue.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы сделать полную предварительную загрузку, Вам нужно использовать технологию SSR (Server-Side Rendering).
Это возможно осуществить с помощью:

- [Quasar Framework for SPA](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-spa/introduction)
- [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/)
- [Vue SSR Renderer](https://ssr.vuejs.org/api/#createrenderer)

Да, прийдется повозиться. Но результат и быстродействие того стоит.
А если Вы сможете корректно настроить кеширование данных, если у Вас есть отдача с бэкенда, то Ваше приложение будет "летать".

Удачи Вам в интеграции.